# python regex repeated pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match:

[document n] m

in order to get rid of [document n] only when n=m

where n is any number

So [document 34] 34 will be a match but [document 34] 45 would not because the numbers are different

So far I have this:

```
import re
text = "[document 23] 23 and [document 34] 48 are white"
text = re.sub(r"(\[document \d+\] )(\d+)",r"\2. ",text)
```

But this does not assure thar the the numbers are equal.

Any idea?

Comment: `d` matches `d`, `\d` matches digits.

Comment: `\d+` instead of "+d\"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```py
\[document\s+(\d+)]\s+\1(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPZzLT/2). Replace with `\1`. *Details*:

- `\[document` - `[document` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\1` - backreference to Group 1
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MFus2E):

```py
import re
text = "[document 23] 23 and [document 34] 48 are white [document 24] 240 text"
print( re.sub(r'\[document\s+(\d+)]\s+\1(?!\d)', r'\1', text) )
## => 23 and [document 34] 48 are white [document 24] 240 text
```